# jquery code selector

Tags: jquery

I have this code that someone else wrote and am wondering, what this jQuery code is selecting? Is this valid jQuery code?

```
var a = $("<h3/>").append($("<a/>", {
    href  : "/comic/title.html",
    class : "comic-link"
}).text("comic-name"));
```

I have never seen HTML tags being used like `<h3/>` or `<a/>`.

Comment: This: `$( '<h3>' ).append( '<a href="/comic/title.html" class="comic-link">comic-name</a>' )`

Comment: The `<a/>` syntax is a shortcut for an empty tag. It could also be written as `<a></a>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `$("<h3/>"` creates a new h3 element
2. `$("<a/>", { attributes})` creates an `<a/>` with those attributes
3. `.text()` appends the text
4. `var a =` the whole un-attached newly created DOM element (wrapped in a jQuery object)

Comment: for step 4... isn't it a jQuery object and not *yet* a DOM element?

Comment: @Hristo good point, `var a =` is a jQuery object and a newly created, though un-attached, DOM element.

Answer (score 6):

The above snippet does not select anything, it creates DOM elements and subsequently manipulates them.

See [here for the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) of this method.

Answer (score 5):

This is **not selecting anything**, it is **creating jQuery object**.

As stated in [`jQuery()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it has  somewhere within the string). If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as explained above. But **if the string appears to be an HTML snippet**, jQuery attempts to **create new DOM elements as described by the HTML**. Then **a jQuery object is created and returned** that refers to these elements.

So, basically, to be more specific: jQuery creates DOM elements, then creates jQuery objects for them, and then it returns them. This is what happened. It did not include selecting anything.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really selecting anything. It'll create a new `<h3>` element and insert the anchor as a child...

```
<h3>​
    <a href=​"/​comic/​title.html" class=​"comic-link">​comic-name​</a>​
</h3>​
```

So then your variable `a` will be assigned a jQuery object that represents this.

Answer (score 2):

Normally `$("<h3/>")` notation is for creating a new H3 element which you can append later on.  I've done this like `$("<h3/>").html("Text").appendTo("..");`  So maybe the appendage part is missing here.

Answer (score 2):

It is creating an `<h3>` element and inserting (appending) a link inside it.

```
<h3>
    <a href="/comic/title.html" class="comic-link">comic-name</a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) on this one.